# vendor.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxxxx.com/abc/def failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

Tags: apache, websocket, rhel7, shibboleth

I am facing above error in apache 2.4.6

My connection configuration is below.

```
<Location /abc>
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
    ShibRequestSetting applicationId protected
    ShibRequestSetting entityID https://example.com
    Require shib-session
    Require valid-user
    ShibUseHeaders On
    ProxyPass https://example.com
    ProxyPassReverse https://example.com
</Location>
```

```
<Location /abc/def>
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
    ShibRequestSetting applicationId protected
    ShibRequestSetting entityID https://example.com
    Require shib-session
    Require valid-user
    ShibUseHeaders On
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) "wss://example.com:443/def" [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) "https://example.com:443/def" [P,L]
 </Location>
```

`abc` and `def` are the paths for the url

It is throwing websocket handshake error in logs.
In UI it shows there is transport error

Please help me what I am doing wrong.Thnaks